# Can't use Jio and data on another sim together!

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, dual-sim

I have Moto Z play. It is a dual sim device.I have inserted Jio and Vodafone sim.

Once I am switching Vodafone for data. It is automatically switched Vodafone sim to 4G.

Is anyway to use data using another sim and JIO sim together?

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My OnePlus 3T lets me change the data SIM, but the problem is that not both SIM is a phone can be 4G / 3G, if one SIM is 4G / 3G, then the other has to be 2G.

JIO will not stay because Jio is a 4G only network, and it will lose network once other SIM is set as 4G / 3G. You can try using Vodafone's internet in 2G.